# Location of Ubuntu Gnome System Monitor

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal

I'll preface this by saying this is for a course I'm taking. The point of the excercise is to change the label on a button in the Gnome System Monitor.

So far, I've been unable to locate the source for the program. I'm unsure if it would be behind the root folder, and don't have a huge desire to go digging through root, usr, lib, etc. unless I have no other choice. System file search doesn't turn up anything useful. Finding the source of the process takes me back to /home/user/. I would appreciate any advice. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the tools, Luke:

```
                # where is the file?
w3@aardvark:~(0)$ type -p gnome-system-monitor
/usr/bin/gnome-system-monitor
                # what package owns the file?
w3@aardvark:~(0)$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/gnome-system-monitor
gnome-system-monitor: /usr/bin/gnome-system-monitor
                # what files are in that package?
w3@aardvark:~(0)$ dpkg -L gnome-system-monitor
                  ...<snip>...
```

That should probably let you accomplish the task, but, if not,

```
sudo apt-get install apt-src
apt-src install gnome-system-monitor
```

should give you the source.